Simple objects in category of quasi-coherent sheaves
Let $X$ be a scheme. Exercise 6.5L in Vakil's FOAG asks to show that the simple objects in $QCoh_X$ (i.e. quasi-coherent $\mathcal O_X$-modules that are not $0$ and have no non-trivial quasi-coherent subobjects/quotients) are precisely the structure sheaves of closed points.
This has been asked before here, but I am not satisfied with the answer. It claims that for a simple quasi-coherent $\mathcal F\ne0$ there exists $x\in X$ such that $\mathcal F\rvert_x\ne0$. But this is not clear why this is the case, for example for general quasi-coherent sheaves $\mathcal F$ we can very well have $\mathcal F\rvert_x=0$ for all $x$, but $\mathcal F\ne0$. Note that here $\mathcal F\rvert_x$ is the pullback of $\mathcal O_X$-modules to $\operatorname{Spec}k(x)$.
Another approach to the question I thought of is to reduce to the affine case. For affine schemes the result is clear and if we could somehow show that the restriction of a simple quasi-coherent module to an open affine is $0$ or again simple the result should follow without much difficulty. Now if the scheme is qcqs this is easily proven, because then the open immersions of affines are quasi-compact and we can apply Stacks 01PE (2) to deduce that the restriction of a simple sheaf to an open affine restriction is $0$ or again simple. Now this Mathoverflow answer seems to give a proof of this without any extra hypothesis (in fact for a general ringed space, not even scheme), but again I am not happy with it: The argument is as follows: $M$ is the sheaf on $X$, $U$ an open subset. If $M\rvert_U$ is not simple and not $0$, then it admits a non-trivial quasi-coherent quotient $N$. Then consider the non-zero map $M\to i_*(M\rvert_U)\to i_*N$. Since $M$ is simple this is injective, but this gives a contradiction once we restrict it to $U$ again. I don't see how we can use here that $M$ is simple, because we only know it is simple in the catogory of quasi-coherent sheaves and $i_*N$ need not be quasi-coherent (so it seems the Mathoverflow question is about simple modules which happen to be quasi-coherent rather than simple objects in the category of quasi-coherent modules).

Yes indeed, my bad; the sheaf $\mathbb Q\in\mathrm{QCoh}(\mathrm{Spec}\ \mathbb Z)$ dies under pullback to any closed point.

I am a bit confused as to what this means...do we mean that $\mathscr F$ is a simple q.c. sheaf then $\mathscr F\cong \iota_*O_{{x}}$ for some closed point $x\in X$? Here I am taking $O_{{x}}$ to be the sheaf corresponding the residue field at $x$.

@Chris Yes, that's also how I interpret the question

This cannot possibly hold because there are schemes without closed points.

@MartinBrandenburg Yes, but is it clear that these schemes admit simple quasi-coherent sheaves?

Edit:This proof now contains a gap.

Let X be a scheme and $\mathcal{O}_X$ be the structure sheaf. Suppose that $M$ is a simple object in $QCoh_X$. 
We shall show that $M$ is a finite type quasi-coherent module. Suppose there is a morphism $f:\mathcal{O}_X\to M$. Then we obtain an exact sequence\begin{equation}
\mathcal{O}_X\to M\to \mathrm{coker}f\to 0.
\end{equation}
Then we must have $\mathrm{coker}f\cong M$ or $\mathrm{coker}f=0$ since $QCoh_X$ is an abelian category. If $\mathrm{coker}f=0$ for some $f$, then those $f$ is surjective, we are done. And if $\mathrm{coker}f\cong M$, then it is a $0$-morphism. That is $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{O}_X,M)=0$. Then $M$ is trivial, which should not be the case. 
Now encoutering a lemma, for any morphism of schemes $f:Y\to X$, the pullback of a finite type quasi-coherent module $\mathcal{F}$ is of finite type and we have $\mathrm{Supp}(f^{*}\mathcal{F})=f^{-1}(\mathrm{Supp}(\mathcal{F}))$.
Since pullback is right exact and commutes with colimits, $f^{*}\mathcal{F}$ is finite.
Since $\mathcal{F}$ is of finite type, $\mathcal{F}_x$ is finite. For any point of $X$, if $\mathcal{F}_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}k(x)=0$, then we have $\mathcal{F}_x=\mathfrak{m}_{X,x}\mathcal{F}_x$.  Then by Nakayama lemma, we obtain $\mathcal{F}_x=0$. We have
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}_x\neq 0\Leftrightarrow \mathcal{F}_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}k(x)\neq 0.
\end{equation}
The converse is obvious. Given $y\in Y$ such that $f(y)=x$. $y\in \mathrm{Supp}(f^{*}\mathcal{F})$ means that $(f^{*}\mathcal{F})_y=\mathcal{F}_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}\neq 0$. And $(f^{*}\mathcal{F})_y\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}} k(y)\neq0\Leftrightarrow \mathcal{F}_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} k(x)\neq 0$. Then it is clear that $y\in \mathrm{Supp}(f^{*}\mathcal{F})$ if and only if $x\in f^{-1}(\mathrm{Supp}(\mathcal{F}))$.
Now suppose that $Z=\mathrm{Supp}(M)$ and recall that the support of a finite type module is closed. For each point $p\in Z$, $\overline{\{p\}}\subseteq Z$ since $Z$ is closed. Then each $p$ gives out a subobject of $M$ via pullback and pushforward, which is nontrivial by the lemma. Hence $\overline{\{p\}}=Z,\forall p\in Z$, which is impossible unless $\{p\}=Z$.(sending $p$ to $\overline{\{p\}}$ is bijective)
I believe this proof is correct. It does not assume that $X$ has a closed point and makes sure that the pullback is nonzero. Also the pushforward of closed immersion preserves quasi-coherence.

Thanks for your answer, but why does $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{O}_X,M)=0$ imply that $M$ is trivial? It seems to me this only means that $M$ has no global sections, but it is certainly possible for a non-zero quasi-coherent module to have no global sections.

@leoli1 Yes, my bad. You are right and I did miss it. I should find a way to fix it in my free time.

This argument requires the existence of a scheme structure on any closed subset $Z\subset X$, such that the inclusion map $Z\hookrightarrow X$ becomes a closed subscheme. This is not introduced until later in Vakil's book.
EDIT: there is a gap in the proof of the first Lemma. See comments.

Lemma: Let $F$ be a simple quasicoherent sheaf on $X$ and suppose $Z\subset Supp(F)$ is closed. Then $Z=Supp(F)$.
Proof: Let $i:Z\hookrightarrow X$ be the inclusion of the closed subscheme $Z$ (say with the reduced scheme structure on Z). We have a surjection $F\to i_* i^*F$ (for the definition of $i^*$ see Vakil 7.2.D). Since $F$ is simple (and $i_* i^*F$ is also quasicoherent), this must be an isomorphism. But $Supp(i_*i^*F)=Z$. ENDPROOF
Lemma: If $p\in Supp(F)$ then $\overline{\{p\}}\subset Supp(F)$.
Proof: Just pick any $q\in\overline{\{p\}}$ and go to an affine neighbourhood $Spec(A)$ of $q$. Then we have prime ideals $P\subset Q$ of $A$ and an $A$-module $M$ such that $M_P\neq 0$. Then clearly $M_Q\neq 0$ as $M_P$ is a localization of $M_Q$. ENDPROOF
Lemma: If $p\in Supp(F)$ then $\overline{\{p\}}= Supp(F)$.
Proof: Combine two previous Lemmas.
Lemma: If $\overline{\{p\}}=\overline{\{q\}}$ then $p=q$.
Proof: Go to an affine $Spec(A)$ containing $p$. Since $p\in\overline{\{q\}}$, we have also $q\in Spec(A)$. So we have prime idelals $P,Q$ in $A$ and $V(P)=V(Q)$. This implies $P=Q$, so $p=q$. ENDPROOF
Lemma: If $p\in Supp(F)$ then $\{p\}$ is closed and $\{p\}=Supp(F)$.
Proof: We have $\overline{\{p\}}=Supp(F)$. If $q\in\overline{\{q\}}$ then $q=p$ by previous Lemmas. ENDPROOF
Conclusion: We must have $Supp(F)=\{p\}$ for some closed point $p$. Also $F_p$ must be a simple $O_{X,p}$-module, so it must be $O_{X,p}/m_{X,p}=k(p)$ and so $F=i_*k(p)$.

Why is $F\to i_*i^*F$ an isomorphism? To deduce that we would need to know that it is non-zero but it is not clear to me why that is the case (it would need to involve the assumption that $F$ is simple, as you could have $i^*F = 0$ for general quasi-coherent modules)

Good point. We still need to show that $i_*i^*F\neq 0$.

Locally it's something like showing $M/PM \neq 0$ if $M_P\neq 0$. This would follow from Nakayama if M were finitely generated. Still need to think about it..

So one would have to prove that a simple object in $Qcoh_X$ all whose fibres are zero must vanish. I have no idea how to do this.
